# SQL query on wp_postmeta

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to find a way to set the meta_value of one meta_key to the meta_value of another meta_key for each individual post_id.

I have two meta_keys - 'url' and 'link'.

The 'link' key contains affiliate links that need to be removed by essentially mirroring the values held in the 'url' key which simply contains a standard link to the target site.

I need to do this for the entire wp_postmeta table, I need to make 'link' equal 'url' for each post_id. I can't just replace them globally as each post_id has a different and unique 'url' value.

Hugely grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try (backing up your DB first):

```
update wp_postmeta h, wp_postmeta p
set h.meta_value = p.meta_value
where h.meta_key = 'link' AND
      p.meta_key = 'url' AND
      p.post_id = h.post_id
```